Model's following entity return empty while data in database
I created a model called userProfileModel that returns entities called (id, name, List)
User_Profile_model.dart
class UserProfileModel extends User {
  @override
  final String email;
  @override
  final String username;
  @override
  final String imageUrl;
  @override
  final String bio;
  @override
  final String name;
  @override
  final int followingCount;
  @override
  final int followerCount;
  @override
  final int postCount;
  @override
  final bool isVerified;
  @override
  final String uid;
  final List<FollowProfileModel> followings;
  final List<FollowProfileModel> followers;

  UserProfileModel({
    required this.email,
    required this.username,
    required this.imageUrl,
    required this.bio,
    required this.name,
    required this.followingCount,
    required this.followerCount,
    required this.postCount,
    required this.isVerified,
    required this.uid,
    required this.followings,
    required this.followers,
  }) : super(
          email: email,
          username: username,
        );

  factory UserProfileModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json,
      List<FollowProfileModel> follower, List<FollowProfileModel> following) {
    print('follow model push');
    print(follower);
    print(following);

    return UserProfileModel(
      email: json['email'],
      username: json['username'],
      bio: json['bio'],
      imageUrl: json['imageUrl'],
      name: json['name'],
      followingCount: json['following_count'],
      followerCount: json['follower_count'],
      postCount: json['post_count'],
      isVerified: json['is_verified'],
      uid: json['uid'],
      followings: following,
      followers: follower,
    );
  }

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'email': email,
      'username': username,
      'bio': bio,
      'imageUrl': imageUrl,
      'name': name,
      'following_count': followingCount,
      'follower_count': followerCount,
      'post_count': postCount,
      'is_verified': isVerified,
      'uid': uid,
      'followings': followings,
      'followers': followers,
    };
  }
}

The function that call to find follower/followings did return a List and It paste in fromJson function
  @override
  Future<UserProfileModel> getProfile(String uid) async {
    try {
      final userResponse =
          await supabaseClient.from('users').select().eq('uid', uid).single();

      final followers = await getFollowerList(uid);

      final followings = await getFollowingList(uid);
      print('followers: $followers');
      print('followings: $followings');
      print(UserProfileModel.fromJson(userResponse, followers, followings));

      return UserProfileModel.fromJson(userResponse, followers, followings);
    } catch (e) {
      throw ServerException(e.toString());
    }
  }

This function is called from other class to try to check if the current user_id is in followings list of the userProfileModel
    String uid = Supabase.instance.client.auth.currentUser!.id;
    print('uid $uid');
    print('target id');
    print(userProfileModel.username);
    print(userProfileModel.followers);
    print(userProfileModel.followings);
    for (final follower in userProfileModel.followers) {
      print('this code is running');
      print(follower.uid);
      if (follower.uid == uid) {
        isFollowed = true;
        break;
      }
    }

The function did print out userProfileModel.username and id but following is empty although the Json function did pass in the required data.
I expect to be able to acquire the userProfileModel.followers and the loop execute as intended.
